# Checkout second Git branch without losing local changes

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, workspace, git-checkout

I have checked out a particular branch from my master. I created new classes propery files etc. in my local Eclipse and did the testing. I have not added/committed those classes/files to my local git repo. So after this successful prototype testing if I want to switch to another branch, how can I do it without losing local changes.

Once I check out the second branch my local changes will be overwritten?  I am not sure if my changes will have to be discarded before the checkout of second branch to be possible.

Comment: if you are using source tree, stash the changes give it a name, switch to other branch, and when you comeback, re apply the stash to get your changes back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is not certain you would lose changes (and in fact if you were to, `git checkout` would warn you), but it would be best to either stash your changes with `git stash` or just go ahead and commit your changes before checking out the other branch.

Comment: Thanks! So my chsnges will always remain associated with the old branch, correct? I cannot stash them away, and bring them back in a new branch.

Comment: No, if you wish to stash them and apply the stash in a new branch, you can totally do that.

Answer (score 3):

Use `git stash`.

> git-stash - Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away

See more in the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

If you have untracked new files, be sure to use the `-u` flag, as includes files git hasn't tracked yet.

Once you're ready to bring your stashed changes back, use `git stash pop`.

```
$ git stash -u
$ git checkout <branch>
$ # do work
$ git checkout <oldbranch>
$ git stash pop
```